# Duplicate Element IDs from AJAX Loaded Content

Tags: html

I'm having an issue where I'm loading 3 DIV's from an AJAX source. The returning HTML looks a little like:

```
<div>
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
  <input id="firstName" name="firstName"....
</div>
```

So imagine this block duplicated 3 times in the same DOM. The problem is when I click on the label in the 3rd loaded DIV, its highlighting the text box in the 1st loaded DIV. So now what I have are 3 blocks of HTML where the ID's are clashing.

Does anyone know of any work around for this?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. CSS selection isn't the issue for me. The problem is the default behaviour by the browser when you specify the "for" attribute on a label. I can't use that attribute in this scenario as I have no control over telling the browser which element specifically to make the label for, in duplicate element blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not compliant to the standard to have multiple elements with the same id. As a result IE, Firefox behaves one way and Chrome behaves another way.

One way is to modify the ids as they are loaded from the AJAX source. You could have a placeholder id served up like `id="UNIQUE_id"` and then use the `.html().replace(/UNIQUE_/g,`**`something_unique`**`));` where **`something_unique`** could be just a serially incremented number...

[html](/questions/tagged/html)[html5](/questions/tagged/html5)

Comment: Thats a great idea, thanks! I could just append the date/time.

Comment: This idea doesn't fly when I try to put it in to practice due to CSS/JS applied to the elements that depend on the IDs. Any other thoughts about this Peter?

Comment: You could apply CSS by class or through a regex match, such as div[id^='unique_'] and by using unique_{date/time} as the unique id, ie. going with my example: something_unique has a non-unique partion that you find by using regex selectors.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I wasn't aware of Regex selectors in CSS at the time. Great thinking.